# upgrading from angular cli 1.7 to 12

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, angular-cli

is there any step by step guide for upgrading from 1.7 to 12/11. I have an app in 1.7 but can't find any step by step here [upgrading angular](https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=2.0-12.0)

can I assume it is the same as upgrading from 2.0

this is my package json

```
{
  "name": "app-name",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "test-chrome": "ng test --browsers Chrome",
    "test-extra-debug-info": "ng test -sm=false",
    "test-create-coverage": "ng test -sm=false --code-coverage=true",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "stylelint": "stylelint src/*/.scss",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "bundle-report": "ng build --prod --stats-json && webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/stats.json -m static -r reports/analyzer/report.html",
    "release": "npx semantic-release"
  },
  "release": {
    "branches": [
      "master",
      "aws-pipeline"
    ],
    "ci": false,
    "dryRun": false,
    "plugins": [
      [
        "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer",
        {
          "preset": "conventionalcommits",
          "releaseRules": [
            {
              "type": "docs",
              "scope": "README",
              "release": "patch"
            },
            {
              "type": "refactor",
              "release": "patch"
            },
            {
              "type": "style",
              "release": "patch"
            }
          ],
          "parserOpts": {
            "noteKeywords": [
              "BREAKING CHANGE",
              "BREAKING CHANGES"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
     ,
      [
        "@semantic-release/changelog",
        {
          "changelogTitle": "Changelog {^_^}"
        }
      ],
      [
        "@semantic-release/git",
        {
          "assets": [
            "CHANGELOG.md",
            "package.json"
          ],
          "message": "chore(release): ${nextRelease.version} [skip ci]\n\n${nextRelease.notes}"
        }
      ]
    ]
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "prepare-commit-msg": "./buildscripts/prepare-commit-msg.sh $HUSKY_GIT_PARAMS",
      "commit-msg": "commitlint -E  HUSKY_GIT_PARAMS"
    }
  },
  "commitlint": {
    "extends": [
      "@commitlint/config-conventional"
    ],
    "rules": {
      "subject-case": [
        2,
        "never",
        [
          "start-case",
          "pascal-case"
        ]
      ]
    }
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/common": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/core": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/forms": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/http": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/router": "4.4.6",
    "@ng-idle/core": "2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@ng-idle/keepalive": "2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@types/jspdf": "^1.1.31",
    "@types/query-string": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/stacktrace-js": "0.0.32",
    "chart.js": "2.6.0",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "is-mail-fine": "^1.0.3",
    "jspdf": "^1.3.5",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^2.3.2",
    "ng2-charts": "1.6.0",
    "ng2-validation": "4.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "query-string": "^5.1.0",
    "rxjs": "5.1.0",
    "stacktrace-js": "^2.0.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.4.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "4.4.6",
    "@types/google.analytics": "0.0.39",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.45",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "husky": "4.2.5",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-reporters": "^2.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.2.0",
    "karma-browserstack-launcher": "^1.5.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "2.1.1",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.32",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "2.0.1",
    "ng2-mock-component": "0.0.6",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.0.2",
    "npm-audit-html": "1.4.0",
    "protractor": "^6.0.0",
    "ts-mocks": "^0.2.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "tslint-defocus": "^2.0.3",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3",
    "semantic-release": "17.0.7",
    "@semantic-release/changelog": "5.0.1",
    "@semantic-release/git": "9.0.0",
    "stylelint": "9.10.1",
    "stylelint-config-recommended": "3.0.0",
    "stylelint-prettier": "1.1.2",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "0.4.6",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "3.8.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "1.12.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.10.3",
    "@commitlint/cli": "9.0.1",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "9.0.1",
    "conventional-changelog-conventionalcommits": "4.3.0"
  }
}


ng --version

    _                      _                 __ _     _
   / \   _ _   _ _ _   | | _ _ _ _     / _| |   | _|
  / △ \ | '_ \ / ` | | | | |/ _` | '_|   | |   | |    | |
 / _ \| | | | (| | || | | (| | |      | |_| |__ | |
//   \\_| ||\, |\,||\,||       \_|__|__|
               |_/

Angular CLI: 1.7.4
Node: 14.16.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 4.4.6
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router, tsc-wrapped

@angular/cdk: 2.0.0-beta.12
@angular/cli: 1.7.4
@angular/material: 2.0.0-beta.12
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/core: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.3.2
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.2.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.10.2
@schematics/angular: 0.3.2
@schematics/package-update: 0.3.2
typescript: 2.3.4
webpack-bundle-analyzer: 3.8.0
webpack-dev-middleware: 1.12.2
webpack-dev-server: 3.10.3
webpack: 3.11.0
```

Comment: Note: the package.json shows this is definitely *not* AngularJS. See [@angular-cli updating](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli#updating-angular-cli) notes.

Answer (score 0):

The link you have shared is the process for the migrating `angular 2.0` to angular latest version. When you try updating the above with existing cli or the steps provided, it will work.

You can check [here](https://update.angular.io/?v=4.4-12.0) though Angular doesn't recommended to switch major version like this(Angular 4 -> Angular 11/12).

Comment: I think cli 1.7 isn't angularjs. I think angularjs is pre- 1.4 and anything upwards is angular

Comment: Can you share the details of `ng --version` ?

Comment: Angular cli comes in angular 2+, we don't have cli in AngularJS. And I mentioned Angular version. I mean Angular cli and angular are two diff things.

Comment: I have added y package json file

Comment: It is `Angular 4` and you can follow the steps mentioned on angular website.

Comment: @crashmstr he has just updated the package.json and it seems the angular version is 4+.

Comment: thanks but I am sure the last time I worked on the project angular 2 wasn't released. I am sure we were using 1.7 I may be wrong but my intuition tell me it was 1.7

Comment: @JackM If the shown package.json is your current one, there is *no* references to any AngularJS packages, which ended with 1.8.x. Your title mentions specifically upgrading/updating Angular CLI, which has its own distinct version numbers and is different from upgrading AngularJS or Angular frameworks.

Comment: Angular cli comes with angular 2, it has nothing to do with AngularJs.

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara The reason I mention AngularJS is that your answer references upgrading AngularJS to Angular, which is not relevant at all since there are no AngularJS packaged listed.

Comment: I have added the results of ng --version

Comment: @crashmstr, Thanks I have updated the answer now with the updated question details.

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara I have added the ng --version printout and it clearly say it is cli 1.7.4

Comment: @JackM if you update the angular version it will also update the angular cli. Your angular version is 4+ at that time when you have this version angular cli was 1.7. Niw if you want to update the angular version it will update angular cli too. I am not sure what ia confusing you?

Comment: thnks very much

Answer (score -1):

AngularJS and Angular are more like different frameworks. Take a look at this which helps you migrate from AngularJS to Angular: https://angular.io/guide/upgrade

Comment: Indeed, michael is right.  you will also find people recommending to rewrite the app from scratch in angular, which might be better sometimes as Angular and AngularJS are quite different.